# How to implement a search by multiple params in spring boot if I have unrelated entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working in a search by multiples parameters, all of them are optional. Immediately I thought in *Criteria API*, but here's a particularity of my develop. The thing is, the main table I need to build the query is an unrelated entity:

```
main_table       table1      table2       table3
```

```
id_main_table   id_table1    id_table2    id_table3
code_table      code_table1  code_table2  code_table3
```

where `code_table` may contains any value of `code_tableN`

I've read that *Criteria API* doesn't support unrelated entities yet.

I was thinking to send the `WHERE` clause as a string param to the repository, something like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT entity FROM ... WHERE " + where)
List<Entity> findEntitiesByParams(@Param("where") String where);
```

but that's not possible.

I'd like to avoid a native query, if it's possible.

Any ideas? Thank so much.

Comment: all tables have same structure?

Comment: No, only these four tables are involved.

Comment: they have different columns?

Comment: Yes, and the structure of code_tableN is different too.

Comment: Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname FROM Author a");
List<Object[]> authors = q.getResultList();

Comment: but  I still dont see what kind of obejct you want to return, if different table map to different objects

Comment: The min amount of code would be CrudRepository

Comment: Not necessarily, I'd like to avoid native query if is possible but I don't have any restrictions.

Comment: In fact, I don't like this database structure, the DB was developed by others. Tables 1, 2 and 3 represents different kinds of products and the main table represents nonconformities that these products may to be involved. So, I need to return NonConformity objects.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table T1 linked to a table T2 by a foreign key. Then you can do

```
@Query(select t1 from TableOne t1 join fetch t1.childTwo t2 where t1.property = ?1  and t1.attribute = ?2 and t2.childProperty = ?3)
public Optional<TableOne> getChildTableTwo(String property, Integer attribute, Double childProperty);
```

for example. And notice that this is HQL syntax, so not reliant on a particular SQL dialect.

Judging from your question, you are interested in doing something similar but using multiple tables (and multiple joins). As far as I know, this is only possible if each table is linked by a foreign key relation - the repository in mind should be of an entity that is related to all other entities of interest, i.e.,

```
T1 (parent) -> (child) T2 (parent) -> (child) T3 (parent) -> (child) T4
Or, 
T1 (parent) -> (child) T2
            -> (child) T3
            -> (child) T4
, for example.
```

So T1 would have an `@OneToMany` and a foreign key table would have an `@ManyToOne` if a primary key was linked to multiple foreign keys. And if a foreign table was also a parent table, it would have both an `@OneToMany and an @ManyToOne` if it had a key that linked to multiple children. You would be required to have some sort of association between the tables in order to perform a query like the one in the example above.

To make the parameters optional you may need to get a little creative - I don't know a best practice for that. One solution could be `where (T.property = ?1 OR T.property = null) && ...`, for example.

Let me know if there's more to your question that I'm not addressing. I'm unsure whether you are more interested in performing a query that makes use of multiple tables or if you just wanted to see how `?1` could be references by `String property` for example. The latter case works because `?1` references the first parameter in the signature btw.